# Create login in android studio for a spring boot server-side with spring security

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a java spring boot application with some web services and to access them you need to login first (the login is made with spring security). I also want to create an android app to login there and access my services. 
I know that for a web app I just need to add a `login.html` file in `src/main/webapp` folder of my project and to notify about that in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method overridden from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class.
How can I create the login in my android app and how to notify spring-security from my server application about that?

Here is my spring-security configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/userPage").hasAuthority("USER")
      .antMatchers("/adminPage").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
      .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(encoder());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make an API call from your mobile app on Login action. 
I have done the same.I had a spring boot REST service that would authenticate the user ad return a sessionID to be uses throughout that login. You can check the below example.

```
 void login(username,password,withSession){
  try {
        bb.put("outputSchema", "VIEW_DATA");
        parameters.put("userId", username);
        parameters.put("password", password);
        parameters.put("filter", withSession);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String URL ="http://localhost:8080/login"+userName ;
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    final JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL,
            parameters,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        res=rps.parse(response);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Connection timed out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Not able to 
                      connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Or you can check this for further explanation:- 
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial/

Comment: Ok! I'll try that. And on server-side I need to keep the default spring-security login? `         .formLogin()
         .and()
         .httpBasic()`

Comment: I don't have a /login controller. The default login page is triggered automatically by spring-security when I try to access a service.